# Remove specific fields and show other fields in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I would like to ask for ways to solve this MySQL issue. 
Currently, I have this select query

```
SELECT username, friend_username from friends
WHERE (username = "apple" or friend_username = "apple");
```

and it shows this **Friends** Table (below).

```
Friends Table
------------------------------
| username | friend_username |
------------------------------
| apple    | orange          |
| apple    | pear            |
| durian   | apple           |
------------------------------
```

But I would like to execute a select query to make it look like this (below).

```
------------
| username |  
------------
| orange   |
| pear     |
| durian   |
------------
```

Is there any possible ways to achieve this? Appreciate the help! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
select case when username = 'apple' then friend_username else username end username
from friends
where 'apple' in (username, friend_username);
```

The `where` clause uses `in` to filter on rows where either `username` or `friend_username` is equal to `'apple'`. Then, the `case` expression in the `select` clause displays the "other" column.